# How to solve this error message "File &quot;/web/xxx.jsp&quot;" not found

Tags: jsp, wso2, wso2-as, wso2-esb

I started implementing carbon component. So back-end runtime was implemented and tested. Now need to create front end UI component. So this is my component.xml file which is placed under resources/META-INF.

```
<component xmlns="http://products.wso2.org/carbon">
<menus>
    <menu>
        <id>orderprocess_menu</id>
        <i18n-key>orderprocess.menu</i18n-key>
        <i18n-bundle>../web/org.wso2.carbon.OrderProcess.ui.i18n.Resources</i18n-bundle>
        <parent-menu>manage_menu</parent-menu>
        <link>../web/orderprocess/orderprocess.jsp</link>
        <region>region1</region>
        <order>50</order>
        <style-class>manage</style-class>
        <icon>../log-admin/images/log.gif</icon>
        <require-permission>/permission/protected/manage</require-permission>
    </menu>
</menus>
```

Then I can see a new item in menu bar after copying generated jar files into dropins folder. But the problem is ones I click it I am getting a runtime exception like this.

```
File &quot;/web/orderprocess/orderprocess.jsp&quot; not found
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.handleMissingResource(JspServlet.java:417)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:384)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
...
```

Still no idea how to solve this.  Any help on this would be appreciated.

Note: I tried to deploy on both **WSO2 ESB and WSO2 AS**.

Answer (score 0):

Change it as follows

```
<component xmlns="http://products.wso2.org/carbon">
<menus>
    <menu>
        <id>orderprocess_menu</id>
        <i18n-key>orderprocess.menu</i18n-key>
        <i18n-bundle>org.wso2.carbon.OrderProcess.ui.i18n.Resources</i18n-bundle>
        <parent-menu>manage_menu</parent-menu>
        <link>../web/orderprocess/orderprocess.jsp</link>
        <region>region1</region>
        <order>50</order>
        <style-class>manage</style-class>
        <icon>../log-admin/images/log.gif</icon>
        <require-permission>/permission/protected/manage</require-permission>
    </menu>
</menus>
```

Comment: Actually I eventually found the correct configuration. In your answer, link tag should be <link>../orderprocess/orderprocess.jsp</link>. But this is a little bit annoying. Isn't it. Because orderprocess.jsp is inside /web/orderprocess folder and component.xml file is inside META-INF folder. The path to jsp page should be given without considering the first directory. Here web directory. How does it happen?